# Read an excel from a URL

Tags: excel, pandas

I am trying to read an excel file from the following URL: http://www.ssf.gob.sv/html_docs/boletinesweb/bdiciembre2020/III_Bancos/Cuadro_17.xlsx

I used the code:

```
ruta_indicadores = 'http://www.ssf.gob.sv/html_docs/boletinesweb/bdiciembre2020/III_Bancos/Cuadro_17.xlsx'
indicadores = pd.read_excel(ruta_indicadores)
```

But when i run the code, the dataframe is empty, but the file is not, so i dont know why it isn't reading excel file.

Here is the screenshoot for the excel file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the pd.read_excel() function by default read the first sheet, but the table you want have a special sheet name, which is "HOJA1".

Here is the code that worked:

```
ruta_indicadores = 'http://www.ssf.gob.sv/html_docs/boletinesweb/bdiciembre2020/III_Bancos/Cuadro_17.xlsx'
indicadores = pd.read_excel(ruta_indicadores, sheet_name='HOJA1')
```

further more, a more robust solution:

```
ruta_indicadores = 'http://www.ssf.gob.sv/html_docs/boletinesweb/bdiciembre2020/III_Bancos/Cuadro_17.xlsx'
indicadores_dict = pd.read_excel(ruta_indicadores, ,sheet_name=None)
# remove the empty sheet
sheetname_list = list(filter(lambda x: not indicadores_dict[x].empty, indicadores_dict.keys()))
df_list = [indicadores_dict[s] for s in sheetname_list]
```

ref. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's, first of all, discuss the Scenario that **Why your `Code` is not able to print `Output`**. Then we will move towards how we can `resolve` it. The `Issue` was :-

- You are directly fetching `Table` from `URL`. So, it has some `Cache` in `Sheet`. So, due to this, your `pd.read_csv()` module is not able to find your `Primary` Sheet.

How I found that there is another `sheet` in your `data`. For that kindly follow the `code` given below:-

```
# Import all important-libraries
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Load 'Cuadro_17.xlsx' Excel Sheet to Workbook
indicadores = load_workbook(filename = "Cuadro_17.xlsx")

# Print Sheet Names of 'Cuadro_17.xlsx'
indicadores.sheetnames
```

```
# Output of above Cell:-
['Cognos_Office_Connection_Cache', 'HOJA1']
```

As you can see our `first sheet` is `Cognos_Office_Connection_Cache` and we can't `fetch` it.

---

### Appropriate Solution in this Scenario:-

Now we know that our `data` has been stored in `HOJA1` `Sheet`. So, we can fetch that specific `Sheet`. and another important thing is your `Data` contains `Multi-Indexing`. So, we have to `fetch data` accordingly. `Code` for the Same was stated below:-

```
# Import all important-libraries
import pandas as pd

# Store 'URL' in 'ruta_indicadores' Variable
ruta_indicadores = 'http://www.ssf.gob.sv/html_docs/boletinesweb/bdiciembre2020/III_Bancos/Cuadro_17.xlsx'

# 'Read CSV' from 'URL' Using 'ps.read_excel()' Module and also Specifies 'Sheet Name', 'Starting Range' of 'Table' and 'header' for 'Multi-level Indexing'
indicadores = pd.read_excel(ruta_indicadores, sheet_name = 'HOJA1', skiprows = 7,  header = [0, 1])

# 'Drop' unnecessary 'Column'
indicadores.drop('Unnamed: 0_level_0', axis = 1, inplace = True)

# Rename Child level Column of 'Conceptos'
indicadores.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1_level_1': ''}, inplace = True)

# Remove 'NaN' Entries from the 'indicadores' Data
indicadores = indicadores.fillna('')

# Print Few records of 'indicadores' Data
indicadores.head()
```

- **I can't `print` that big `Output` here. So, I have `Attached Sample Output` of above mentioned `Code` in the `Image` given below:-**

[image: Output Image]

As you can see we have fetched `Table` successfully. Hope this Solution helps you.